# Render multiple inputs React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a simple **Budget app** using **React**. The user can add Income/Expense Description and Value by filling out the inputs and the final result gets added to the Expenses/Incomes lists.

I managed to add the Income/Expenses values (numbers): I've created a setState with incomes: [1, 3, 4], map around the income array and print out the values by updating the state.

I can't understand how to add the description. I've checked some questions here on Stack but they only use setState and creating a state for each element (incomes, incomeValues, expenses, expensesValue), which is not what I want.

Is there a way to do this without involving too many states? Maybe using an Object?

[Github Link](https://github.com/niclamarino/100_projects/tree/master/16_react_budget)

Comment: so you want to have a key-value pair instead of the integers in the 'incomes' array?

Comment: Sure, you can have an array of objects. It's really up to you how you want to model your data, is not a single right way.

Comment: I've used  <Income description={description} key={i} income={income} />...but of course description is returned undefined.

So I should be doing something like this?

setState() {
   incomes: {value: [2,333,29], description: ['Number one', 'Number Two', 'Three']}
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your state is an object

```
{
  monthlyBudget: 0,
  incomesSum: 0,
  expensesSum: 0,
  incomes: [0],
  expenses: [0]
}
```

What you could do instead of adding more numbers to the incomes array is add objects to the incomes array. Exactly like you guessed.

```
{
  monthlyBudget: 0,
  incomesSum: 0,
  expensesSum: 0,
  incomes: [
    { amount: 0, description: 'some description' },
    { amount: 1, description: 'second description' },
  ]
  expenses: [0]
}
```

in which case you would still use map to access the properties of the object.

```
this.sate.incomes.map(income => {
  // do something with income.amount
  // do something with income.description
})
```